# Scroll & Focus attribute in IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, iframe

I have two setoff Iframe(Left and Right) on a single page. Plus a list of topics on top. when I click the topic list it should scroll and focus my iframe span attribute{Value}.

```
<p style="font-family:Calibri;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;font-size:10pt;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt"><span data-dt-uuid="uuid-10">Country, </span><span data-dt-uuid="uuid-11">M.M. </span><span data-dt-uuid="uuid-12">2020 </span></p>
```

Like this, I have multiple

and  tags. Every span has an attribute like data-dt-uuid="uuid-11", data-dt-uuid="uuid-12" and so on.

when I click the Country list it should scroll and focus my country span. Next, if I click Name it should focus on the span with attribute data-dt-uuid="uuid-12", .like this so on. the topic list has the referral id as span attribute.

Comment: Please, (unless you're building HTML-Email) stop using inline `style` (or javascript) attributes. Styles should go to their appropriate tag `<style>` or rather into a separate CSS file.

Comment: This HTML content is from another src. I just load it in IFrame